# Export all WhatsApp Chats at once

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, export

how can I export all WhatsApp Chats at once, without having to click every single one of them to export it.
Can someone help me with that problem?

BR Sarah

Comment: There's no such functionality yet, so you're gonna have to export each

Comment: Isn't there a possibilty to write a clickbot for whatsapp web?

Comment: not that I know of

Comment: Is there any hack involving decrypting a WhatsApp back up on Google Drive? Or alternatively, a paid tool that does this for you?

Comment: The only solutions I've come across for this specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15427040/6728517 Disclaimer: the answer is old and I haven't tested it. Having researched this a little, it looks like exporting chats individually is the only other option.